# VMware-ESXI 7.0 Limit number of logins from the same user

Tags: vmware-esxi

How can i limit number of logins(sessions) from the same user? I'm using VMware host client.
Basically i just want user to login once and from one device only.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of a Vmware specific setting you could change to achieve this result. The authentication mechanisms in Vmware are standard but basic.

Documentation [here](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.html.hostclient.doc/GUID-C2C963BE-4E92-41BC-AF84-01A4F6A6EC50.html)

The recommended methods would be to:

1. Use a third party. BeyondTrust has a privilege access management service that can also include web services. Users would log in to beyondtrust and then access the web service. You can use a firewall to only allow the BeyondTrust appliance as the allowed network device and you woud achieve isolation. If you have a Palo Alto firewall, you can use [Authentication Policies](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/pan-os/8-1/pan-os-admin/authentication/authentication-policy)
2. Segment your network. Much more complicated but you could create a privileged access workstation and only allow access to those machines with your network administrator's assistance.

Best of luck!

Comment: I've seen that documentation and haven't found anything useful about my problem, I think you're right, there is no such mechanism in vmware. Anyway thank you for the answer.